# Search by part of text in Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to write a **scraper** for a web page catalog, but in different specs tables dimensions are written with different measurements. For example length is measured in meters or centimeters.

```
<td class='charname'>
<span> Length, m </span>
</td>
```

or

```
<td class='charname'>
<span> Length, cm </span>
</td>
```

I can find a `<span>` element by text in case of exact match:

```
length = props_table.find('span', text='Length, m')
```

How to modify it so it finds any `<span>` with Length independently on it's measurement (m, cm, etc)?

Comment: what do you mean by find independently? what is the code of the site? what is the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [find_all](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all),

```
for item in props_table.find_all("span"):
    if "Length" in item.text:
        print(item.text)
```